# Combinations of large number in c++

Tags: c++, combinations

How to compute combination for large number in c++? (eg. nCr n=1000 and r=500) Requirement is of last 9 digits of combination. I tried using long long int variable but still my code is able to solve and display last 9 digits of 50C19 but not more than that.

```
const long int a = 1000000000;
long long int ncr(int n,int r)  
{
 long long int fac1 = 1,fac2=1,fac;
 for(int i=r;i>=1;i--,n--)
    {
        fac1 = fac1 * n;
        if(fac1%i==0)
            fac1 = fac1/i;
        else
            fac2 = fac2 * i;
    }
 fac = fac1/fac2;
 return fac%a;
}
```

Comment: Collect the prime factors of the numerator and denominator, and only multiply up at the very end.

Comment: I haven't tried any, but there are several BigInteger C++ class libraries available that you can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just store the factors of the numerator in an array and divide out each factor of the denominator where possible. Finally take the product of the reduced numerators mod 10^9.

Here is some code for your specific example. You need to write a gcd() function.

```
int a[] = { 1000,999,...,501 }; // numerator factors

for (int b = 2; b <= 500; b++) {
  int x = b;
  for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    int d = gcd(x, a[i]);
    if (d > 1) {
      x = x / d;
      a[i] = a[i] / d;
      if (x <= 1) break;
    }
  }
}

// take the product of a[] mod 10^9

int ans = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  ans = (ans * a[i]) % 1000000000;
}
// ans = C(1000,500) mod 10^9
```

A good discussion of other techniques is available here:

http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/3869/best-known-algos-for-calculating-ncr-m